# How to make emacs-org export open a pdf in fit-to-width mode?

Tags: shell, pdf, emacs, org-mode

[SOLVED] 
The `org-mode` part of my `.emacs` file contains the following section:

```
'(org-file-apps
  (quote
   ((auto-mode . emacs)
    ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
    ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
    ("\\.pdf\\'" . "evince %s"))))
```

It works fine, I use this to view documents that I exported from org to latex. My problem is: I'd like to replace

`("\\.pdf\\'" . "evince %s")`

with

`("\\.pdf\\'" . "evince -w %s")`

But then no output will appear.

Comment: I edited my question, hope it's more useful now.

Answer (score 1):

[edit: I was wrong! Emacs *does* open documents using commands like

`evince -[Option] %s`

all I actually know is it doesn't open them in fit-to-width mode when using (('evince' or 'xpdf') and the wm 'awesome').]

The problem was solved by using the pdf-viewer "zathura".

[should I delete the whole question?]

Comment: Do not delete it, you never know who'll be coming some time ;) BTW, do you know how to launch zathura maximized and/or fullscreen?